# how to wrap combo-box options text in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have a below combobox in the HTML:

```
<lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-combobox class="slds-cell-wrap slds-text" label="combo-box" options={comboOptions}>
            </lightning-combobox>
        </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

JS:

```
comboOptions = [{ value: 'This is a very very long label', label: 'This is a very very long label' },
{ value: 'This is a very very long label', label: 'This is a very very long label' },
{ value: 'This is a very very long label', label: 'This is a very very long label' },
{ value: 'This is a very very long label', label: 'This is a very very long label' },
{ value: 'This is a very very long label', label: 'This is a very very long label' },
];
```

it renders like below:

[image]

If the option string is longer then it truncates the string, I tried using slds-cell-wrap but still options are being truncated instead of wrapping, could someone please suggest how to wrap the combobox options.

**Update**
using below component from the lightning base component recipe doesn't have an option property instead tried to set items property but it shows something like below

[image]

Please confirm if is there any way to wrap the option text of combobox

Comment: Did you ever find a good option for this or did you go down the route of you making your own combobox?

Comment: Unfortunately, no in house solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a custom combobox component, if you need text wrapping. *Easiest approach would be to create a replica of the base components involved. You can check out the source code [here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc) for `baseCombobox` & `baseComboboxItem` components. A one line code change (i.e., remove the `slds-truncate`) in your replicated custom component's `inline.html` file of `baseComboboxItem` should work. Note that I've personally not tried this out, but should be possible.*

---

You cannot use class attribute (CSS) on the LWC base component (combobox) or unless SF provides a new attribute (or some kind of variant). Reason being,

1. CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_dom))
2. Don’t depend on the internal markup or CSS classes of a base Lightning component as they can change in future releases. You can’t override the style for a base Lightning component ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_slds))
3. Base components provide a class attribute so that you can add a utility class or custom class to the **outer elements of the components** ([ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_slds))

As mentioned in point # 3, the slds you specify in class attribute doesn't get applied to the inner elements of the component.

Combobox would get rendered something like this in chrome (*below HTML shows only for one element*). Note that innermost span element has the `slds-truncate` which causes option labels to get truncated. Point # 2 mentioned above recommends not to depend on this current HTML structure for styling.

```
<div lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" id="dropdown-element-341" data-dropdown-element="true" role="listbox" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid slds-dropdown_left">
    <lightning-base-combobox-item lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" data-item-id="input-341-0" data-value="This is a very very long label" role="option" id="input-341-0-341" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-media_center slds-media_small slds-listbox__option_plain" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
        <span class="slds-media__body">
            <span title="This is a very very long label" class="slds-truncate">This is a very very long label</span>
        </span>
    </lightning-base-combobox-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried to follow your answer but not able to render a combobox using the base combobox and the code that you have posted throws error "invalid attribute ightning-basecombobox_basecombobox=", please suggest

Comment: Could you update the question with some details of what you have tried out?

Comment: I tried to render c-base-combobox  and it is showing a picklist without any options and a placeholder , there is no API property which I can set for the options

Comment: I have updated my question, please suggest.